# How programmatically to get Jenkins user id?

Tags: jenkins

I would like to pass the user id of the person who started a Jenkins job to a script. The output of 'env' indicates no environment variables are set and the output of 'ant -v' indicates no properties are set. How do I access the user id of the person that started a job? (I understand that triggers can start jobs, but for this job, it will always be a person).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the job executor:

```
curl -s "${BUILD_URL}/api/json" | \
python -c '\
    import json; \
    import sys; \
    obj = json.loads(sys.stdin.read()); \
    print [ \
        cause["userId"] \
        for action in obj["actions"] \
        if "causes" in action \
        for cause in action["causes"] \
        if "userId" in cause][0];'
```

Also see [How to set environment variables in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins) which explains how to pass it into a script.

Comment: I had to pass --user username:password as an additional argument to curl.

Answer (score 0):

```
BUILD_START_USER=`curl ${JOB_URL}'lastBuild/api/json' | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.loads(sys.stdin.read());print obj["'"actions"'"][1]["'"causes"'"][0]["'"userId"'"]'`
```