# How to set environment variables in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, environment-variables

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
AOEU=$(echo aoeu)
```

and have Jenkins set `AOEU=aoeu`.

The *Environment Variables* section in Jenkins doesn't do that. Instead, it sets `AOEU='$(echo aoeu)'`.

How can I get Jenkins to evaluate a shell command and assign the output to an environment variable?

Eventually, I want to be able to assign the executor of a job to an environment variable that can be passed into or used by other scripts.

Comment: EnvInject plugin is having some serious security vulnerability. Now Jenkins is having inbuilt support for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53430757/1753177

Comment: @lambodar the link just goes to the question

Comment: @Z.Cochrane, it's a link to an answer that has been deleted by the author.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

This can be done via [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) in the following way:

1. Create an "Execute shell" build step that runs:

   ```
   echo AOEU=$(echo aoeu) > propsfile
   ```
2. Create an *Inject environment variables* build step and set "Properties File Path" to `propsfile`.

**Note**: This plugin is (mostly) not compatible with the Pipeline plugin.

Comment: EnvInject doesn't handle the situation I gave above:


    [EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
    AOEU=$(echo aoeu)

    [EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
    [EnvInject] - Unset unresolved 'AOEU' variable.

Comment: It seems that I did not quite get what it was that you wanted. My meaning was that you first run a shell build step where you write something like `echo 'AOEU=' > propsfile` and then `echo \`echo aoeu\` > propsfile`. In the next build step you load propsfile (the contents of which is now `AOEU=aoeu`).

Comment: That solution uses Unix shell syntax and won't work on windows.

Comment: @fbmd I'm running it on Windows. You just need to make sure you have `sh` on the path.

Comment: EnvInject does not work if the "execute shell" exits with an error because the build does not proceed to the injection part.

Comment: Using the managed script is also the same result, in case if anyone is wondering. The propsFile will be under the /workspace of your project directory

Comment: What's wrong with just adding a "Execute shell" with `export foo="bar"` ?

Comment: @Vitim.us, `foo` will get exported in that specific shell action but not in other actions.

Comment: Doesn't work with Maven plugin.  EnvInject looks for propsfile before any pre-build step is executed.

Answer (score 124):

#### The simplest way

You can use [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to injects environment variables at build startup. For example:

[image: Add key=value (bash OK!) under 'Build Environment'->'Inject environment variables to the build process' -> 'Properties Content']

#### How you know it's working

[image: EnvInject - Variables injected successfully]

Comment: Try setting the value based on the output of a shell command.

Comment: @NoelYap Works too, as long as in the end the line evaluates to `key=value`. In my use case I generate the line completely:

`cat app/build.gradle | grep "def majorVersion" | python -c 'import sys,re,os; print("VERSION_NUMBER="+re.findall(r"[\d+\.]+", sys.stdin.read())[0]+os.environ["BUILD_NUMBER"])'`

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer what version of EnvInject are you using? With 1.91.3, a command like yours is interpreted as "cat=app...".  Would be great if this feature was supported, but I'm getting the sense that this may have worked for you by accident.

Comment: FWIW, I did get my variables to work by creating a property file first using the Script Content box (not shown) and then reading it back in using the Path field shown in the screenshot above.  It only supports hard-coded absolute paths though which is a bummer.

Comment: @killthrush Not sure, I'm also using 1.91.3. I haven't tried with a simple  `echo FOO=BAR`, but that seems like a good test of whether it would work for you.

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer Yeah, I tried a lot of variations of echo, printf, and eval and finally gave up.  Wonder if it's a shell idiosyncracy of some kind.  I'm running Jenkins 1.620 with Ubuntu 14.04.  Thanks just the same - it's a tantalizing possibility that this could work!

Comment: attempting to assign a value to the output of a shell command is not working for me either: `BUILD_DATE=date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S"` and `BUILD_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S")` and `BUILD_DATE=\`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S"\`` did not work for me

Comment: is it possible to do it globally to apply for every build?

Comment: @scottyseus did you ever solve that? Am trying to do the same.

Comment: @AndyHayden it has been a while since I last did this, but I believe my solution was to add a build step to capture the date in a file, and then I somehow injected that file into the build.

Comment: @scottyseus I ended up using this https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin worked like a charm.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38286383/1240268

Comment: If I use this method, how can/do I manipulate the variable inside an "Execute shell" step? If I simply set the same variable inside the step it doesn't get set. For example if set it in one "Execute shell" step, and echo it in another "Execute shell" step, it doesn't show the changes.

Answer (score 72):

In my case, I needed to add the `JMETER_HOME` environment variable to be available via my Ant build scripts across all projects on my Jenkins server (Linux), in a way that would not interfere with my local build environment (Windows and Mac) in the `build.xml` script. Setting the environment variable via **Manage Jenkins - Configure System - Global properties** was the easiest and least intrusive way to accomplish this. No plug-ins are necessary.

[image: Manage Jenkins Global Properties]

---

The environment variable is then available in Ant via:

```
<property environment="env" />
<property name="jmeter.home" value="${env.JMETER_HOME}" />
```

This can be verified to works by adding:

```
<echo message="JMeter Home: ${jmeter.home}"/>
```

Which produces:

> JMeter Home: ~/.jmeter

Comment: That is a global property.  It will effect ALL jobs on Jenkins.  Supposed I just want this property for one job?

Comment: I've added to Manage Jenkins - Configure System - Global properties, the following: `git` `/path/to/my/git` and `PATH+git` `/path/to/my/git`. However, if I am trying to access `git` from the a `Jenkins pipeline script`, I get: `/bin/sh: git: command not found`.

Comment: I just needed to set up JAVA_HOME environment variable and this answer was the one that helped me.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky In that case, could you use an environment variable that only that particular job would be aware of?

Answer (score 42):

In my case, I had configure environment variables using the following option and it worked-

```
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties -> Environment Variables -> Add
```

Comment: This is the best way

Comment: How to access this Global properties' Environment variables from Jenkins Build "Execute shell" ?

Comment: three hours no luck and then your comment saved me. Thanks man!

Answer (score 27):

You can try something like this

```
stages {
        stage('Build') {
            environment { 
                    AOEU= sh (returnStdout: true, script: 'echo aoeu').trim()
                }
            steps {
                sh 'env'
                sh 'echo $AOEU'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't parse.

Comment: This formatt is for the Jenkinsfile pipeline project. What job type are you using this snippet in?

Comment: This works perfectly in a `Jenkinsfile` for a pipeline (not job)! That's awesome, thanks for it!

Comment: How to make this a global variable so that `AOEU` can be referenced in subsequent stages?

Answer (score 26):

You can use [Environment Injector Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject) to set environment variables in Jenkins at job and node levels. These are the steps to  set them at job level:

1. From the Jenkins web interface, go to **`Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins`** and install the plugin.

[image: Environment Injector Plugin]

2. Go to your job **`Configure`** screen
3. Find **`Add build step`** in **`Build`** section and select **`Inject environment variables`**
4. Set the desired environment variable as VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE pattern. In my case, I changed value of USERPROFILE variable

[image]

If you need to define a new environment variable depending on some conditions (e.g. job parameters), then you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47511305/1808829).

Answer (score 16):

[EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) aka (*Environment Injector Plugin*) gives you several options to set environment variables from Jenkins configuration.

By selecting `Inject environment variables to the build process` you will get:

- `Properties File Path`
- `Properties Content`
- `Script File Path`
- `Script Content`
- and finally `Evaluated Groovy script`.

---

`Evaluated Groovy script` gives you possibility to **set environment variable based on result of executed command**:

- with `execute` method:

```java
    return [HOSTNAME_SHELL: 'hostname'.execute().text, 
        DATE_SHELL: 'date'.execute().text,
        ECHO_SHELL: 'echo hello world!'.execute().text
    ]
```

- or with explicit `Groovy` code:

```java
    return [HOSTNAME_GROOVY: java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(),
        DATE_GROOVY: new Date()
    ]
```

(More details about each method could be found in build-in help (?))

---

Unfortunately you can't do the same from `Script Content` as it states:

> Execute a script file aimed at setting an environment such as creating
>   folders, copying files, and so on. Give the script file content.  You
>   can use the above properties variables.  **However, adding or overriding
>   environment variables in the script doesn't have any impacts in the
>   build job**.

Answer (score 15):

There is [Build Env Propagator Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-env-propagator/) which lets you add new build environment variables, e.g.

[image: Jenkins Build - Propagate build environment variables]

> Any successive Propagate build environment variables step will override previously defined environment variable values.

Comment: Thank you! Build Env Propagator Plugin worked when I tried it, and it's great to have the ability to set environment variables during the Build steps!

Answer (score 8):

> This is the snippet to store environment variable and access it.

```
node {
   withEnv(["ENABLE_TESTS=true", "DISABLE_SQL=false"]) {
      stage('Select Jenkinsfile') {
          echo "Enable test?: ${env.DEVOPS_SKIP_TESTS}
          customStep script: this
      }
   }
}
```

Note: The value of environment variable is coming as a String. If you want to use it as a boolean then you have to parse it using Boolean.parse(env.DISABLE_SQL).

Answer (score 7):

Normally you can configure *Environment variables* in *Global properties* in *Configure System*.

However for dynamic variables with shell substitution, you may want to create a script file in Jenkins HOME dir and execute it during the build. The SSH access is required. For example.

1. Log-in as Jenkins: `sudo su - jenkins` or `sudo su - jenkins -s /bin/bash`
2. Create a shell script, e.g.:

   ```
   echo 'export VM_NAME="$JOB_NAME"' > ~/load_env.sh
   echo "export AOEU=$(echo aoeu)" >> ~/load_env.sh
   chmod 750 ~/load_env.sh
   ```
3. In Jenkins Build (*Execute shell*), invoke the script and its variables before anything else, e.g.

   ```
   source ~/load_env.sh
   ```

Comment: unfortunately did not work for me. after `sudo su - jenkins`, still `echo $USER` gives me `root`.

Comment: @prayagupd You need to simulate a full login, so use `su -l` parameter to do that, otherwise ask a separate question.

Comment: @kenorb after invoking the script, how do I read env variable again?

for example, this does not work

sh """
source ~/load_env.sh
echo "VM_NAME: $VM_NAME"
echo "VM_NAME: ${VM_NAME}"
"""

Answer (score 6):

extending the answer of @JSixface:

To define environment variables **globally** for access from within all the stages of a *declarative pipeline*, you can add the `environment` section within the `pipeline` block.

```yaml
pipeline {                                                                                               
  agent {                                                                                                
    node {                                                                                               
      label 'myAgent'                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                      
  environment {
    AOEU = "${sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo aoeu').trim()}"                
  }                                                                                                      
  stages {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [Environment Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin) ([GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/environment-script-plugin)) which is very similar to [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). It allows you to run a script before the build (after SCM checkout) that generates environment variables for it. E.g.

[image: Jenkins Build - Regular job - Build Environment]

and in your script, you can print e.g. `FOO=bar` to the standard output to set that variable.

Example to append to an existing `PATH`-style variable:

```
echo PATH+unique_identifier=/usr/local/bin
```

So you're free to do whatever you need in the script - either `cat` a file, or run a script in some other language from your project's source tree, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason `sudo su - jenkins` does not log me to `jenkins` [user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38286755/432903), I ended up using different approach.

I was successful setting the global env variables using using jenkins `config.xml` at `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` (installed in Linux/ RHEL) - without using external plugins.

I simply had to stop jenkins add then add `globalNodeProperties`, and then restart.

Example, I'm defining variables `APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT` and `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` to `continious_integration` below,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>

  <globalNodeProperties>
    <hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
      <envVars serialization="custom">
        <unserializable-parents/>
        <tree-map>
          <default>
            <comparator class="hudson.util.CaseInsensitiveComparator"/>
          </default>
          <int>2</int>
          <string>APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT</string>
          <string>continious_integration</string>
          <string>SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE</string>
          <string>continious_integration</string>
        </tree-map>
      </envVars>
    </hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
  </globalNodeProperties>
</hudson>
```

Comment: Is there a way such as using cloudbees API or any kind of restAPI to change the value of Jenkins environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of the following ways listed below:

1. Use [Env Inject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) for creating environment variables. Follow this for usage and more details https://github.com/jenkinsci/envinject-plugin

   2. Navigate below and can add

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties -> Environment Variables -> Add

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scripted Pipeline syntax that we use is this:

```
env.AEOU = sh label:'set env var',
                returnStdout: true,
               script : '''#!/bin/bash
                   echo "aeou"
               '''
sh label:'checkit',
 script : '''#!/bin/bash
    echo "${AEOU}"
 '''
```

Note the use of `triple-single-quote` notation for the `script` parameter to the `sh` step. This ensures that the `${AEOU}` does not get interpolated by Groovy and does get interpolated by the bash shell.

Answer (score -3):

We use groovy job file:

```
description('')
steps {
    environmentVariables {
        envs(PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD: true)
    }
}
```