# How to set Environment Variable so that it can be used in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, email-ext, continuous-delivery

I am using an Environment Variable so that that it can be modified and Recipient List will consume that environment variable.

So this value is passed as a build parameter:
[image]

Followed to that I am modifying it. Just as an example:

[image]

Now I am accessing this value in the recipient list:
[image]

Unfortunately Jenkins is not able to get this new value. It is using the old value. How this behavior can be fixed?

Comment: Try : 
echo %email_list%

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins/10626193#10626193

Comment: To Not Again-> echo %email_list%  does not work. It results into: 
Successfully sent to the following addresses: %email_list%
Error sending to the following INVALID addresses: echo

Answer (score 4):

We need to use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). One of the features is a build step that allows you to "inject" parameters into the build job from a settings file.

Create a property for the email list in the env.properties file:

```
echo "email_list=`dummy@test.com`"> env.properties
```

It will create the properties file in the job workspace directory.

```
env.properties
```

In Recipient list access this variable using the following:

```
"$email_list"
```