# Delaying Parameter Variable expansion in Jenkins EnvInject

Tags: parameters, jenkins, environment-variables

I'm trying to delay the expansion of variables within Jenkins Parameters *until* the parameter *used*.  For example:

I have a job parameter "EMAIL_SUBJECT" which might contain a reference to a variable that will change throughout the build.  EG: "My build of $GIT_HASH".  Where the value of "GIT_HASH" might change throughout the build.

In old versions of EnvInject every time EMAIL_SUBJECT was used it would reference the newest value of GIT_HASH. Like this:

1. Start build with parameter EMAIL_SUBJECT="My build of $GIT_HASH"
2. Do some work and set GIT_HASH=**A**
3. EMAIL_SUBJECT is "My build of **A**"
4. Do some work and set GIT_HASH=**B**
5. EMAIL_SUBJECT is "My build of **B**"

However in newer versions of EnvInject (1.77+) EMAIL_SUBJECT is evaluated once and never updates.  So the above becomes:

1. Start build with parameter EMAIL_SUBJECT="My build of $GIT_HASH"
2. Do some work and set GIT_HASH=**A**
3. EMAIL_SUBJECT is "My build of **A**"
4. Do some work and set GIT_HASH=**B**
5. EMAIL_SUBJECT is "My build of ***A***"

I've tried escaping the variable with backslashes in the parameter but EnvInject doesn't like that either and escapes my escapes, so the result ends up being the same string just with a "\" proceeding the value.
    EMAIL_SUBJECT=My build of \$GIT_HASH
Ends up outputting:
    My build of \A

My question: Is there a way to stop EnvInject from overriding a parameter?  Or any environment variable for that matter?

Comment: You can add a build step of updating the environment `Inject environment variables`

Comment: I'm not sure how that applies?  I know how to inject environment variables in my project, but I don't see how that helps me keep variables from expanding in parameters.  Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: I was thinking you could rebuild the environment variable in an intermediate step between steps but I guess you don't hard code it but set it based on some condition. This may be what you're looking for where you build a props file and load it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins