# Environment variable for the GitHub organization in Jenkins workflow

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

Is there anyway that I can get the GitHub organization on which I'm running the Jenkins workflow through the Jenkinsfile.

I can check it through the BUILD_URL

```
def url = env.BUILD_URL
sh 'echo $BUILD_URL'
```

But can I print the GitHub repo url or GitHub organization in the console.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088034

Answer (score 1):

Can print GitHub repo url into Jenkins Console output by running

`sh 'git config --get remote.origin.url'`