# Jenkins build fails & browser does not launch on linux but runs on local machine

Tags: java, linux, selenium, jenkins

I can successfully run my selenium webdriver tests from my local machine(WindowsA), I now want to run my tests using Jenkins (machine B). For my webdriver Tests I see the following output from Jenkins

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
Error: no display specified
```

I've made sure browser and and selenium versions match. I  think this is an issue with my Jenkins(linux) machine. I have `Xvfb` on my linux machine also. I've read articles mention the browser maybe running in HEADLESS mode but seeing as other people are using Jenkins I am cautious before making any changes.

Comment: What are the commands that you are using to run the selenium tests?

Comment: 'clean test'. If I use 'mvn clean test' an error message is displayed for maven.

Comment: It looks like you are not starting Xvfb. Perhaps this will help: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to run the tests without specifying a [DISPLAY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-display-environment-variable#answer-432257) and from what I read in your question I'm not sure if you are really using Xvfb or not and also if the "machine B" has a X server or not. Well, if machine B doesn't has a X server you need to run Xvfb in order to simulate one, then you need to set the $DISPLAY environment variable to the value that the Xvfb server will be listening to and finally you can run the selenium driver. An example:

```
# The Xvfb server will listen for connections as server number 4
Xvfb :4 &
# set $DISPLAY value to the one defined in your Xvfb server instance
export DISPLAY=:4
# run the selenium driver
java -jar /path/to/your/driver/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
```

Comment: Is there a way to set Display from Jenkins?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins.

Comment: So I should just take your example (or similar) inject using jenkins. Install selenium standalone server. And that should be it?

Comment: You will have to adapt those commands to your specific case, since you didn't explain exactly how you are currently trying to run the tests, and there are a lot of ways to do this in jenkins like with simple bash scripts/taskrunners/plugins, I cannot tell you precisely what to do.

Comment: Currently I run my tests from my local machine command line using mvn clean test. My project comprises of maven testng selenium and some javascript

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you more since I never used maven and testng, though I'm pretty sure the problem that you are having is the one described in my answer.