# Prevent Jenkins pipeline commands from being executed in different shells

Tags: git, shell, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following code in my Jenkins pipeline script:

```
sh("alias git='/my/file/path/libexec/git-core/git'")
mvn "-e -X release:prepare"
```

The second line is calling `git` and it fails with:

```
The git-tag command failed.
Command output:
/bin/sh: git: command not found
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to tag SCM
```

That shouldn't happen because I am aliasing it first.

My suspicion is that the statements are ran in different shells.

Is that true?
In which case, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Did you try: mvn -Dgit=path/to/git -e -X release:prepare?

Comment: Yes. Same error.

Comment: And can you provide the pom file?

Comment: I don't think it has any connection with `pom.xml` because that doesn't have any git plugin or dependency.

Comment: What about the fact that the error is raised by maven?

Comment: Also, you might want to have a look here: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html

Comment: Yes, I'm using this plugin, according to the example. I don't think it's an issue with Maven. I suspect it's a problem with the environment on Jenkins.

Comment: And I suppose adding git as an environment variable on your Jenkins is not possible? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins

Comment: Can I use `EnvInject` from a Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `mvn` is in your script (there is no built-in Maven function in Pipeline), but I think you want something like this:

```
sh '''
  export PATH=$PATH:/my/file/path/libexec/git-core/git
  mvn -e -X release:prepare
'''
```

Comment: try `git status` instead of calling Maven, something else must be wrong in your build node.

Comment: `git status` works. So I'm assuming the issue must come from Maven and the way it's calling Git. Maybe it's opening a subshell with no configuration and calling Git there, but I'm not sure. Do you have any idea?