# How do I get jenkins to modify one URL in a series of python test scripts, so I can maintain a single repository

Tags: python, git, selenium, jenkins

I have a Jenkins environment that is running a series of Selenium python tests in both a dev environment and a prod environment (two seperate jenkins pipelines). I'd like to have both my Jenkins environments modify a single URL in each of the python test scripts via some kind of global variable set from within Jenkins so that after the test scripts are pulled from git it modifies that single line in each script and proceeds to run the tests with the appropriate URL parameter given. Is there a shell script that I can write and add to the Jenkins pipeline that will modify the variable in each script before it gets run on Jenkins?

The overall goal is to maintain one directory of tests instead of duplicating the identical test cases and hard coding each of the URLS in place. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set an environment variable in your jenkins configuration, use the environment variable in your test scripts.

One such way to do this is with the [envinject plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject). See [How to set environment variables in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins)