# Java: run jenkins job from GitHub and load credential from another location

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, intellij-idea

So i have Java `Maven` project with `Selenium`.

This protect is hosted on `GitHub` and i also have `Jenkis` job that run this test every night.

Because my test require to login to specific `WebSite` i need to provide the `credential` (email  address and password):

```
emailaddress="myemailaddress@gmail.com"
password="mypassword"
```

so i create `config.properties` file inside my `Intellij` and load this `credential` from this file.

Now because i hosted my project in free account i want to find a way the not everyone could see this `credential` and still be able  to run my tests every night.

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: you can create variables in jenkins(like environmental variables) and use it. And this can be access controlled, based on user permissions

Comment: I probably need to get this variables from Jenkins in my code , can i have code example ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

Comment: And how to get this credentials from my code ?

Comment: Create the credentials in the credentials store of Jenkins and use them in your build..no property files etc. are need. Best avoid them...

Comment: Hi Erofh. How are you executing your selenium project from jenkins? plugin? simple shell commands?

Comment: Using "invoke top level maven targets"

Comment: How? pipeline script, declarative script, execute shell option?

Comment: Well until now i just click on build now button...