# variable set in Windows Powershell of Jenkins build, not available in other build steps

Tags: powershell, variables, jenkins, scope, environment-variables

I have a Jenkins build with one parameter called VERSION.

Based on the length of the variable i am modifying its value in Windows Powershell and then in the next build step, i want to use it.

But the modified value is not being reflected in the next build step execution, it still refer to the intial value entered as a parameter. I tried ENV,script,global none of them seems to work.

Windows powershell build step

input VERSION=1810(via jenkins build)

```
           if ("$ENV:VERSION".length -eq 4)
        {
           $ENV:VERSION = "$ENV:VERSION",3 -join ""  (here it will be 18103)
         }

         Write-Output "$ENV:VERSION" (18103 here aswell)
```

later in the Nexus artifact uploader i refer to this variable as ${VERSION} and the above updated value is not being reflected

```
                 (here it is 1810 and not 18103)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) and set additional `PROJ_VERSION=$ENV:VERSION` variable in your job. In this case it should be working correctly. If it isn't working within `Properties Content` directly, try to use injection via file as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626193/10721592) example.

Answer (score 2):

This is a general issue with environment variable scope. Every process inherits the environment variables from its parent, but has its own copy, and any modifications you make will only be reflected in the current process and child processes.

I think you will have to find some way to pass the value to a future step that doesn't rely on environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I found another option which works in Freestyle project jobs.

the 1st powershell step:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('IMAGE_VERSION', $imageVersion, 'Machine')
```

the 2nd powershell step:

```
$imageVersion = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('IMAGE_VERSION', 'Machine')
```

Comment: This looks like it runs at the machine level.  If so, then running the script multiple times at the same time creates a race condition.