# set a new Enviroment variable in Jenkins Shell scripting

Tags: shell, jenkins

I tried so many ways to store a value in jenkins. But I could not assign a value into a variable in Shell script of Jenkins.

First I have set a ENV variable called **branch** which has the value is ***/release/hotfix**

So I tried to spliit that word and save in new variable like this.

```
VALUE=$($branch | sed -e 's/\*\/.*\///g')
```

I tried so many experiment to save the value. It won't work.

In my research, I found a way to assign a value to variable but the plugin ( [How to set environment variables in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins?noredirect=1&lq=1) ) may not be safe to use.

why cant i save value to variable in Jenkins shell? How do I do that?

Comment: My observation, when you are running multiple shell commands in Jenkins, every line executes on a different shell. 

So, if you want to store the value of some variable and use them, then you have to run them as the same single line command(ugly way).

Comment: ohhh undestood dude. so thats why I could not access the value inside variable . @VaibhavJain

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to achieve this problem.

first I create a file using touch command

```
touch enviroments.cfg
```

Then save value into variable while saving to that file

```
echo "export VALUE=$(echo $branch | sed -e 's/\*\/.*\///g')" >> enviroments.cfg
```

to access the that saved variable again, I reopened that file and get that value like this

```
. './enviroments.cfg' (you can not use **source** command to read, use **dot**(.) instead of **source** command)

echo $VALUE
```

You can read  values anywhere like this.