# Set environment variables from shell script in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I am trying to automate my build using `Jenkins`. My build process needs to execute three different `shell scripts`. The first script sets **some** `environment variables` which is used by the second and the third scripts. 
I am trying with a `pipeline` job in Jenkins where each script is executed stage by stage. However I am unable to get the environment variables from the first script to the next one.

NB: There is a set of variables that are being set.So I don't feel like using a simple variable will do.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set environment variables in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins)

Comment: each shell script executed in like a sub-process, once execution complete, the sub-process is end, any environment variables exported in shell script is also end. Thus you can pass down them to next shell script by `export AAA=...`.  You need write out those export statements into a file, then execute the file in next shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably confusing [declarative pipeline with scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/)

Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)

```
pipeline {
agent any

environment {
    DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
    DB_ENGINE    = 'sqlite'
}

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'printenv'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Jenkinsfile (Scripted Pipeline)

```
node {
withEnv(['DISABLE_AUTH=true',
         'DB_ENGINE=sqlite']) {
    stage('Build') {
        sh 'printenv'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using declarative pipeline. The problem is that the variables that are being set from the script is not known before-hand. So I cannot set it in `environment` block.

Comment: @Jackzz You can add the `environment` section inside the `stage`section