# Jenkins X Passing value of custom variable into helm Values

Tags: devops, continuous-deployment, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, jenkins-x

**Summary**
I have custom variable in Values.yaml file of helm, i need to assign the value of this variable during build release stage.
...
clientname: XYZ
...

**Steps to reproduce the behavior**
I tried to use eskaffold to send the vaule through setEnv

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta2
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: 'myimagename'
    context: .
    docker: {}
  tagPolicy:
    envTemplate:
      template: '{{.DOCKER_REGISTRY}}/{{.IMAGE_NAME}}/{{.CLIENT_NAME}}:{{.VERSION}}'
  local: {}
deploy:
  kubectl: {}
profiles:
- name: dev
  build:
    tagPolicy:
      envTemplate:
        template: '{{.DOCKER_REGISTRY}}/{{.IMAGE_NAME}}/{{.CLIENT_NAME}}:{{.DIGEST_HEX}}'
    local: {}
  deploy:
    helm:
      releases:
      - name: '{{.CLIENT_NAME}}'
        chartPath: charts/'{{.CLIENT_NAME}}'
        setValueTemplates:
          image.repository: '{{.DOCKER_REGISTRY}}/{{.IMAGE_NAME}}/{{.CLIENT_NAME}}'
          image.tag: '{{.DIGEST_HEX}}'
          clientname: 'myclientname'
```

**Expected behavior**
the value of client name Values.yaml set to myclientname

**Actual behavior**
the value in Values.yaml not changed

**Jx version**

```
NAME               VERSION
jx                 2.0.743
jenkins x platform 2.0.1182
Kubernetes cluster v1.12.10-eks-825e5d
kubectl            v1.13.7-eks-c57ff8
helm client        Client: v2.14.3+g0e7f3b6
git                2.16.5
Operating System   CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

**Jenkins type**
 Classic Jenkins

**Kubernetes cluster**
EKS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set environment variables in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins)

Comment: Look at this answer @MawanAlrihawi  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626193/3617531

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io) (new generation) has little to nothing to do with [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io).

Comment: Nice point @masseyb thanks. Didn't see the X at first

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know skaffold is no longer used by the pipeline. They have switched the builder to google kaniko. The best way to insert values into your template is via `charts/myapp/templates/deployment.yaml` and `charts/myapp/values.yaml`.

Try adding the following to
**values.yaml**

```
env:
   clientname: myclientname
```

Update **deployment.yaml** template to substitute value (other vars can be used than env, this was just shown for the purposes of demoing the substitution)

```
# ...
spec:
      containers:
        env:
        - name: clientname
          value: {{ .Values.env.clientname }}
# ...
```

Comment: I use skaffold with the [kaniko](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/builders/docker/#dockerfile-in-cluster-with-kaniko) builder, they’re not mutually exclusive.