# Triggering a downstream job in Jenkins using injected environment variable doesn't work?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

I have 2 Jenkins jobs namely `test-trigger1` and `test-trigger2` and I want to set up `test-trigger1` to trigger `test-trigger2` using an injected environment variable.

So in `test-trigger1`'s `Configure->Build Environment->Inject environment variables to the build process->Properties Content box` I have this

[image]

Then I added a `Build->Execute Shell` step, which simply has

[image]

and a subsequent `Build->Conditional step(single)` step that has

[image]

However, I'm not triggering the `test-trigger2` job, and I see this in `test-trigger1`'s console output

```
(Steps for SCM checkout ommitted)
Run condition [Boolean condition] enabling prebuild for step [Trigger/call builds on other projects]
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
TRIGGER_JOB=false

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[test-trigger1] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins5417082998696567335.sh
+ echo TRIGGER_JOB=false
TRIGGER_JOB=false
+ TRIGGER_JOB=true
+ echo TRIGGER_JOB=true
TRIGGER_JOB=true
[Boolean condition] checking [false] against [^(1|y|yes|t|true|on|run)$] (origin token: ${ENV,var="TRIGGER_JOB"})
Run condition [Boolean condition] preventing perform for step [Trigger/call builds on other projects]
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
[Boolean condition] checking [false] against [^(1|y|yes|t|true|on|run)$] (origin token: ${ENV,var="TRIGGER_JOB"})
Run condition [Boolean condition] preventing perform for step [Builder to mark whether executed]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Apparently, the `Execute shell` step is not setting the injected environment variable correctly, or I'm not setting it correctly? Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: when you update an environment variable in the shell session it applies on in that  session and doesn't affect the Jenkins job, if you want it to take affect you will have to create the parameters in a file and inject them to your build. The question however is how to you want to control the value of the trigger job parameter?

Comment: Thanks Noam. "How do I want to control the value of the TRIGGER_JOB parameter you mean? I need to be able to set its value in an "Execute shell" job. Note above code is a prototype of the real job I have, but if I can make above code work, I can use the solution in my real-world job.

Comment: In that case check out [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626193/13110835) it explains how to use the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to achieve what you want.